# decidability and reducibility

Tags: turing-machines

I am a bit confused on how I can show the finiteness problem is undecidable using Rice’s Theorem.

So I’ve got something like B = { | M is a TM and L(M)- finite}. I thought I could reduce A TM (determine whether a TM accepts a given input which I already know is undecidable) to B but then I’m not sure how I would construct/ describe a new Turing Machine that decides my A?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you seen examples of other reductions?
Note that constructing a reduction and using Rice's theorem are not the same thing. Rice's theorem directly implies that this language is undecidable, since it is a nontrivial semantic property.

Comment: I started by showing that it can accept a given input string so the Language of A would be sigma* so infinite but then I think I also have to show the case where the language could be empty so it would be finite since Ø is finite.

Comment: I can guess what you mean, but it's not clear enough. Try adding to your question a proof-attempt. Start by formally stating what you are trying to do (reduce $A_{TM}$ to the problem), and then show the construction of the reduction you have in mind. We'll take it from there.